# calculation comparing sql timestamp and php date("y-m-d h:i:s")

Tags: php, sql, comparison, timestamp

Is there a way to see if ((the current time - a timestamp in a database)>10 minutes) in php? I have a row in a database called lockout. I have the following code so far:

```
echo $row['lockout'];//returns 2013-05-12 22:04:17
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")//returns 2013-05-12 22:06:32
```

Furthermore does anyone have any ideas why when I insert the current Timestamp in my database, it is about a half hour off, but has the right date and year?

Answer (score 2):

The SQL answer could depend on which SQL technology you use.  To do this in PHP rather than SQL you could use the [diff() method of DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php):

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($row['lockout']);
$datetime2 = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%i minutes');
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function with [relative formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) like `- 10 minutes` to get the desired Unix timestamp:

```
if ( strtotime('- 10 minutes') < strtotime( $row['lockout'] ) ) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php datetime class in php
This has a diff method

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL dialect is MySQL use

```
... WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-lockout>=600 ...
```

or something similar in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your query:

```
WHERE `lockout` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

Or, if you cannot rely on MySQL's time, use

```
mysqli_query('
 ... WHERE `lockout` < DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(' . time() . '), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) ...
');
```

Or, if you are bound to `date(...)`, use

```
mysqli_query('
 ... WHERE `lockout` < DATE_SUB(' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ', INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) ...
');
```

You might want to compare MySQL's and PHP's timezones and your servers' ones (if MySQL and PHP live on separate hosts).

Comment: @ Lukas I'm not doing the calculation comparison in an sql query though. It's in an if statement in my php code. Something like                      if ((date("Y-m-d H:i:s") - $row['lockout'])>600 ){
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;CareMarkLogin2.php'/>";
   }
   else {
    echo "Lockout";
   }